# How to draw mask in real time in qgraphicspacacityeffect by pyqt？

Tags: python, pyqt

```
class CustomItem(QGraphicsItem):

    offset = QPoint(0,0)
    pixmap = None
    brush = None
    p_list = []
    l_Point = QPoint()
    m_Point = QPoint()
    mouseMove = False
    w= 0
    h= 0
    effect = None
    def __init__(self,img):
        super(CustomItem, self).__init__()

        self.w = img.width()
        self.h = img.height()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(img)

        self.mask = CustomMask(self)
        self.mask.setOpacity(1.0)
        self.mask.setEnabled(True)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.mask)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0 ,self.w,self.h)

    def paint(self, painter, Option, widget=None):
        painter.drawTiledPixmap(self.boundingRect(),self.pixmap,self.offset)
        self.update()

class CustomMask(QGraphicsOpacityEffect):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(CustomMask, self).__init__()
        self.paths = []
        self.rect = parent.boundingRect()
        self.background = QPixmap(self.rect.width(),self.rect.height())
        self.background.fill(QColor(0, 0, 0))

        self.pen = QPen()
        self.pen.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        self.brush = QBrush()
        self.brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
        self.brush.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))


    def draw(self, painter):
        super(CustomMask, self).draw(painter)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.setBrush(self.brush)

        if self.paths != []:
            for p in self.paths:
                painter.drawEllipse(p, 100, 100)

        self.update()
```

Comment: explain yourself better I do not understand.

Comment: Add more information about your question.

Comment: I added an item in qgraphicscene, and I want to add an image to the item that can draw a mask in real time. Finally, call setmask function through pixmap in item to make the image transparent